# How to observe Android's Clipboard, really?

Tags: android

I need to detect Android Clipboard's content changes, and register the changes, but I can't really understand how to achieve such result.

There are a lot of clipboard managers around, but I found none open source, and it's difficult to believe they work by checking the clipboard every 15 seconds.

Is there a good method to observe clipboard changes ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.ubervu.com/conversations/rojekti.org/), at least for the Clipper program, they do indeed poll the clipboard - every 5 seconds. There doesn't seem to be anything in the API to do it any other way.

Answer (score 3):

Since API version 11 ("Android 3.0"), there is a [new service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html) and appropriate callback `ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener`