# How to copy highlighted text from a webview in android honeycomb 3.0?

Tags: android, webview, android-3.0-honeycomb, highlight

In Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) we have this feature that when we long press any text on webview it is highlighted & some options come up on the action bar. One of which is copy. When we press copy the highlighted text is copied to the clipboard from where we can retrieve it.

I want to know that how can we do this without pressing the copy button. In other words what functionality is there behind this copy button?

In my application I am required to retrieve this highlighted text from web view but without pressing the copy button i.e. instead of copy button I will press something else and that should get (copy+paste) the highlighted text in a separate dialog.

please help

Comment: try to fetch text from clipboard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977480/how-to-observe-androids-clipboard-really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to implement the same feature, but you would need to have the control of the selected Text.  unfortunately you can't use Selection() in a Webview. Only in Textfields.